# Multiple re-renders breaks CSS transition

Tags: reactjs

I have a draggable React pure component that pushes aside other draggables around it, triggering multiple re-renders.

However when the component is dragged too quickly (causing another re-render to occur before the CSS transition can finish animating) strange behaviours show up. The surrounding draggables will jump around unpredictably.

Everything works fine and transitions smoothly as long as I set a low enough transition time or drag the component slowly enough so that the transition finishes before the next re-render.

I'm using simple CSS transitions inside the component's style props, adding the `transition` property when the component is being actively dragged and removing it otherwise.

```
transition: "all 500ms ease"
```

Examples:

In both gifs, I'm dragging the leftmost panel towards the right. Each time there is a column swap, there is a re-render.

The top gif shows everything functioning as expected when dragging slowly and setting a low 100ms transition time.

In the bottom gif, I'm dragging too quickly causing the component to re-render before the first transition can complete. You can observe the leftmost panel moving out of frame towards the left side even though it's not being dragged.

[image: When you drag it slowly, everything works]

[image: When dragged too quickly, the leftmost panel shifts by itself]

Is there any way to delay re-rendering until the CSS animation is finished?
Is there another solution here that's typically applied for these situations?

Comment: Generally the solution here is to figure out why it's rerendering, because nothing here needs rerendering: you're only moving nodes around in the DOM, so proper use of `key` attributes should not even _trigger_ rerenders of content, it should only do the node reordering. So, because it's _super common_ for folks to forget to do: did you remember to use `key` attributes? And if so, did you remember to properly make them unique _to the element_ instead of mistakenly using array position as if it's a unique key? (`array.map((element,id) => <Thing key={id}/>)` is all too common, and super wrong)

Comment: Would you please include the code you already have?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry, I should have mentioned that the examples above are slightly simplified for the sake of clarity.
 
Those are parent containers that typically contains nodes with properties that change depending on the parents' position.

I am using stable keys unique to each column.

Comment: @macborowy unfortunately I haven't been cleared to post any code at the moment :(

Can I add any additional details that might help clarify? I'm very certain the issue is caused by the transition being cut off by a re-render.

Comment: Then I would recommend paring down your code to a [mcve], in order to elicit sensible recommendations. It's entirely possible the solution here is to not update your subcomponents states just because they got repositioned, but to make it conditional on whether or not the position prior to and at the moment of update are the same position. If they're not, do nothing (and probably schedule a new update for the new position). If they are, then a rerender should be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'll see what I can do wrt a minimal reproducible example.
 
This is precisely what's going on (if I understand you correctly) - only when the dragged component passes a certain threshold does it trigger a state change, which then causes the columns to swap place. Before and up to that point, there is no re-render.